# iOS Button action doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a strange issue with iOS `UIButton`.

I have a `UIViewController` class:

```
@interface CustomViewController : UIViewController
```

Inside of this class I have a label called `customLabel`. In this label I have a button subview:

```
UIButton *addButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];

[customButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customButton addTarget:self action:@selector(customButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[customLabel insertSubview:customButton atIndex:1];
```

And of course, action method:

```
- (void)customButtonClicked
{
    NSLog(@"- (void)customButtonClicked");
}
```

I also have a subclass for this view controller:

```
@interface MyNewCustomViewController : CustomViewController
```

This view controller is loaded inside UIWindow:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController: myNewCustomViewController animated:YES];
```

Everything seems to be fine, label with button are at the correct positions, except the fact, that button click doesn't call action method...

Maybe you know, where the problem could be?

Comment: Try to change the target to `action:@selector(customButtonClicked:)`

Comment: That shouldn't matter since it's not an IBAction. Change it to an IBAction and yes. User interaction enabled on the view? Try just inserting the subview rather than at a specific index. (addSubview will place the view at the top index)

Comment: Then I get warning about undeclared method. This makes sense, because `- (void)customButtonClicked`

Comment: @DCGoD you are right! I am insertng a subclass to `UILabel` class, which has `userInteractionEnabled` set to `NO` by default!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't have another view over top of your current button and user interaction is enabled on the view. This should work.

```
// First make sure userInteractionEnabled is enabled for your custom label which will contain your button as a subview 
customLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

// Then create and add your button as a subview
UIButton *addButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[customButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customButton addTarget:self action:@selector(customButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[customLabel addSubview:addButton]; // Places view on top index
```

Comment: `customLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` fixed this issue!